# Не передаются значения формы в обработчик - jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-form

Здравствуйте! Есть форма, скрипт, обработчик форты. И почему-то в обработчик не попадают значения с формы.
   Скрипт находиться перед формой.

```
<script>
function AjaxFormRequest1(result_id1,contact1,url) {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url:     url,
        type:     "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: jQuery("#"+contact1).serialize(), 
        success: function(response){
            document.getElementById(result_id1).innerHTML = "<p style='color: #87B00A;'><strong>Отправлено! Ожидайте звонка от нашего сотрудника. :)</strong></p>";
        } ,
        error: function(response) {
            document.getElementById(result_id1).innerHTML = "<p>Возникла ошибка при отправке формы. Попробуйте еще раз</p>";
        }
    });
}
</script>

<div id="result_id1"></div>
<form method="post" action="" id="contact1" name="contact1">
    <input id="tel" name="tel" class="txt" placeholder="Номер телефона" style="margin-left: 0px;"><br>      
    <input id="product" name="product" class="txt" style="display: none;" value="123">
    <input id="url" name="url" class="txt" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $pageURL;?>">
    <input id="pricenew" name="pricenew" class="txt" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $prodprice;?>">
    <input id="priceold" name="priceold" class="txt" style="display: none;" value="<?php echo $priceold;?>">
    <input id="button" type="button" class="button validate" value="Отправить" onclick="AjaxFormRequest1('result_id1', 'contact1', 'http://web-site.com/by-one-click2/sendmessage.php')"/>
</form>
```

И сам обработчик

```
if(empty($_POST['tel'] )){
$sendto   = "my-email@gmail.com";
$usertel = $_POST['tel'];
$prod = $_POST['product'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
$pricenew = $_POST['pricenew'];
$priceold = $_POST['priceold'];

$subject  = "Заказ belief ** $prod";

$msg = "<h2 style='font-weight:bold;border-bottom:1px dotted #ccc;'>Запрос</h2>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> $usertel</p>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Товар: </strong> <a href='$url'>$prod</a></p>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Цена: </strong> $pricenew грн.</a></p>";
$msg .= "<p><strong>Старая цена: </strong> $priceold грн.</a></p>";

mail($sendto, $subject, $msg, "Content-type:text/html; charset = utf-8");
}else { echo "<p>Обязательные поля не заполнены. Введите номер телефона</p>";}
```

Comment: Не совсем ясно, к чему в коде приведен ни к чему не привязанный JS-код, в котором магиеческим образом сочетется JQuery и нативный JS. Если уж пользутее jquery то и пишите `$("#" + result_id1).html("<p>...</p>")` вместо `document.getElement...`.

Относительно обработчика, то чтобы посмотреть какие данные приходят в запросе достаточно сделать `print_r($_POST)`. В вашем же скрипте, на первый взляд условие `if(empty())` хочется заменить на `if(!empty)`. А то проверяете что данных  нет, и пытаетесь их извлечь.